# Sinusoidal functions Intersection

Tags: calculus

Finding the intersection equation of two sinusoidal functions denoted as $a_1$. The values of $F_1$ & $F_2$  are equal at $a_1$. What is $a_1$ equal to?

\begin{equation}
F_1 = \alpha \cos(2\pi a_1-2\pi\phi) 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
F_2 = f \cos(2\pi a_1 - 2\pi\psi)
\end{equation}

Comment: The question seems odd. There are so many unknown constants that, I imagine, we could tweak it to have any value! Do you have any more context for the problem?

Comment: Please just check the answer

Comment: Here, I'm not saying that $a_1$ should equal to a value or number!. $a_1$ should have a number but according to the equation above, $a_1$ should meet the answer below.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

$$
\alpha \cos(2\pi a_1-2\pi\phi) =  f \cos(2\pi a_1 - 2\pi\psi)
$$
By using cosine identity the right hand side would be

$$
\alpha \cos(2\pi a_1-2\pi\phi) = f \cos2\pi a_1\cos2\pi\psi+f \sin2\pi a_1\sin2\pi\psi
$$
Dividing the both sides by $\cos2\pi a_1$, we obtain.

$$
\frac{\alpha \cos(2\pi a_1 - 2\pi\phi)}{\cos2\pi a_1} = f\cos2\pi\psi+f \tan2\pi a_1 \sin2\pi\psi
$$
To solve for $a_1$,
$$
\tan2\pi a_1 =\frac{\alpha \cos2\pi a_1 \cos2\pi\phi + \alpha \sin2\pi a_1 \sin2\pi\phi}{f\sin2\pi\psi \cos2\pi a_1} - \frac{\cos2\pi\psi}{\sin2\pi\psi}
$$
But
$$
\tan2\pi a_1 = \frac{\sin2\pi a_1}{\cos2\pi a_1}
$$
Then equation (6) becomes.
$$
\tan2\pi a_1 = \frac{\alpha \cos2\pi\phi}{f\sin2\pi\psi} + \frac{\alpha \tan2\pi a_1 \sin2\pi\phi}{f \sin2\pi\psi} - \frac{\cos2\pi\psi}{\sin2\pi\psi}
$$
To simplify the terms of (7)
$$
\frac{\alpha \cos2\pi\phi}{f\sin2\pi\psi} - \frac{\cos2\pi\psi}{\sin2\pi\psi} = \tan2\pi a_1 -  \frac{\alpha \tan2\pi a_1 \sin2\pi\phi}{f \sin2\pi\psi}
$$
By factoring out $\tan2\pi a_1$ from the right hand side, we get:
$$
\frac{\alpha \cos2\pi\phi - f\cos2\pi\psi}{f\sin2\pi\psi} = \tan2\pi a_1 \left(1- \frac{\alpha\sin2\pi\phi}{\sin2\pi\psi}\right)
$$
Then, $\tan2\pi a_1$ would be
$$
\tan2\pi a_1 =\frac{\left(\frac{\alpha \cos2\pi\phi- f\cos2\pi\psi}{f\sin2\pi\psi}\right)}{\left(1-\frac{\alpha \sin2\pi\phi}{\sin2\pi\psi}\right)} 
$$
More simplification for (8)
$$
\tan2\pi a_1 = \frac{\alpha \cos2\pi\phi-f\cos2\pi\psi }{f\sin2\pi\psi - f\alpha \sin2\pi\phi}
$$
Then $a_1$ equals to
$$
a_1 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\alpha \cos2\pi\phi-f\cos2\pi\psi}{f\sin2\pi\psi - f\alpha \sin2\pi\phi}\right)
$$

Comment: Please who ever vote not useful I need your comments. I'm here to learn not getting only votes!

Answer (score 0):

$$\alpha \cos(  x- \phi) =\beta\cos(  x- \psi) $$

(sorry, I did not like the $f$ and I dropped the $2\pi$ factors) can be expanded as

$$(\alpha\cos( \phi)-\beta\cos( \psi))\cos(  x)+(\alpha\sin( \phi)-\beta\sin( \psi))\sin(  x)=0$$

and

$$\tan(  x)=-\frac{\alpha\cos( \phi)-\beta\cos( \psi)}{\alpha\sin( \phi)-\beta\sin( \psi)}.$$

Comment: No problem about the f, what is the name of your expansion you did above?

Comment: @TahseenSaad: addition formula.

Comment: Great both answers quite close however, the solution is in different ways!

Comment: @TahseenSaad: did you expect different solutions for the same equation ?!

Comment: I think yes, I do.